# ApexCode date value contain time error

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I have this code, for input date then use that date to find the Birthdate range of students. I don't know why, but my whole code is all about Date, but it gave me DateTime, which makes my query can't run properly.

**Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
                access="global"
                controller="LN_Aura_Apex_TimKiemController">
    
    <aura:attribute name="hs" type="HOCSINH__c" default="{ 'sobjectType' : 'HOCSINH__c',
                                                         'HO__c' : '',
                                                         'TEN__c' : '',
                                                         'GIOITINH__c' : '',
                                                         'NGAYSINH__c' : '',
                                                         'DIEM1__c' : '',
                                                         'DIEM2__c' : '',
                                                         'DIEM3__c' : '',
                                                         'LOP__c' : ''}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="lop" type="Map"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ngaysinhTu" type="Date"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ngaysinhDen" type="Date"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="HOCSINH__c">
            <table border="3">
                <tr>
                    <th class="headers" scope="row">Tên:</th>
                    <td class="slds-is-sortable slds-is-resizable" colspan="3">
                        <lightning:inputField aura:id="input"
                                              fieldName="TEN__c"
                                              value="{!v.hs.TEN__c}"
                                              variant="label-hidden"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="headers" scope="row" style="vertical-align: bottom;">Lớp:</th>
                    <td class="slds-is-sortable slds-is-resizable" colspan="3">
                        <lightning:select aura:id="lopOptions"
                                          value="{!v.hs.LOP__c}"
                                          onchange="{!c.onLopChange}" 
                                          variant="label-hidden">
                            <option text="Tất cả lớp" value=""/>
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.lop}" var="lop">
                                <option text="{!lop.value}"
                                        value="{!lop.key}"/>
                            </aura:iteration>
                        </lightning:select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="headers" scope="row">Ngày sinh:</th>
                    <td class="slds-is-sortable slds-is-resizable">
                        <lightning:input type="date"
                                         value="{!v.ngaysinhTu}"
                                         variant="label-hidden"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">~</td>
                    <td class="slds-is-sortable slds-is-resizable">
                        <lightning:input type="date"
                                         value="{!v.ngaysinhDen}"
                                         variant="label-hidden"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th/>
                    <td>
                        <lightning:button class="slds-button 
                                                 slds-button_stretch"
                                          label="Tìm kiếm"
                                          onclick="{!c.timKiem}"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>
        <lightning:datatable keyField="ID"
                             data="{!v.hs}"
                             columns="{!v.columns}"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="false"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Javascript Controller**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.columns', [
            {label: 'Họ', fieldName: 'HO__c', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Tên', fieldName: 'TEN__c', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Ngày sinh', fieldName: 'NGAYSINH__c', type: 'date'},
            {label: 'Giới tính', fieldName: 'GIOITINH__c', type: 'boolean'},
            {label: 'Điểm 1', fieldName: 'DIEM1__c', type: 'number'},
            {label: 'Điểm 2', fieldName: 'DIEM2__c', type: 'number'},
            {label: 'Điểm 3', fieldName: 'DIEM3__c', type: 'number'},
            {label: 'Điểm TB', fieldName: 'DIEMTB__c', type: 'number'},
            {label: 'Tình trạng', fieldName: 'TINHTRANG__c', type: 'text'}
        ]);

        helper.getData(component);
    },
    
    onLopChange: function(component, event, helper)  {  component.find("lopOptions").get("v.value"); },
    
    timKiem : function(component, event, helper) { helper.getSearch(component); },
})
```

**Javascript Helper**

```
({
    getData : function(component) {
        var action1 = component.get("c.getDanhSachLop");
        action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS")
            {
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                var lopMap = [];
                for(var key in result){
                    lopMap.push({key: key, value: result[key]});
                }
                component.set("v.lop", lopMap);
            }
            else if(state === "ERROR")
            {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) { console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message); }
                } 
                else { console.log("Unknown Error"); }
            }
        });
        
        var action2 = component.get('c.getHocSinh');
        action2.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set('v.hs', response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        }));
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action1);
        $A.enqueueAction(action2);
    },
    
    getSearch : function(component) {
        var action = component.get('c.searchData');
        action.setParams
        (
            {ten: component.get("v.hs.TEN__c"),
             lop: component.get("v.hs.LOP__c"),
             ngaysinhTu: component.get("v.ngaysinhTu"),
             ngaysinhDen: component.get("v.ngaysinhDen")}
        );
        alert("Tên: " + component.get("v.hs.TEN__c") +
              " Lớp: " + component.get("v.hs.LOP__c") + 
              " Ngày sinh từ: " + component.get("v.ngaysinhTu") + 
              " Ngày sinh đến: " + component.get("v.ngaysinhDen")
             );
        action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set('v.hs', response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                console.error(errors);
            }
        }));
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**Apex code**

```
public with sharing class LN_Aura_Apex_TimKiemController 
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Map<String, String> getDanhSachLop()
    {
        System.debug('getDanhSachLop starting...');
        Map<String, String> options = new Map<String, String>();
        
        for (LOP__c lop : [SELECT ID, TEN__c FROM LOP__c ORDER BY TEN__c]) {
            options.put(lop.ID, lop.TEN__c);
        }
        return options;
    }
    
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<HOCSINH__c> getHocSinh() {
        return [
            SELECT HO__c, TEN__c, NGAYSINH__c, GIOITINH__c, DIEM1__c, DIEM2__c, DIEM3__c, DIEMTB__c, TINHTRANG__c
            FROM HOCSINH__c
        ];
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<HOCSINH__c> searchData(String ten, Id lop, Date ngaysinhTu, Date ngaysinhDen) 
    {
        System.debug(ngaysinhTu);
        List<HOCSINH__c> getDanhSachHocSinh = new List<HOCSINH__c>();
        List<String> query = new List<String>();
        
        if(ten != null) { query.add('TEN__c LIKE ' + '\'' + ten + '\'' ); }
        if(lop != null) { query.add('LOP__r.ID = ' + '\'' + lop + '\''); }
        if(ngaysinhTu != null) { query.add('NGAYSINH__c >= ' + Date.valueOf(ngaysinhTu)); }
        if(ngaysinhDen != null) { query.add('NGAYSINH__c <= ' + Date.valueOf(ngaysinhDen)); }
        
        String whereClause = '';
        if(query.size() > 0)
        {
            whereClause = ' WHERE ' + String.join(query, ' AND ');
        }
        
        String queryHS = 'SELECT HO__c, TEN__c, NGAYSINH__c, GIOITINH__c, DIEM1__c, DIEM2__c, DIEM3__c, DIEMTB__c, TINHTRANG__c FROM HOCSINH__c' + whereClause;
        System.debug(queryHS);
        getDanhSachHocSinh = Database.query(queryHS);
       
        return getDanhSachHocSinh;
    }
}
```

This is the debug Date value that I get from ngaysinhTu: 2006-04-13 00:00:00

It makes no sense, there are no Datetime only Date. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally, both Date and DateTime are represented with the data structure; a Date has the time component set to midnight of the day. This is reflected in the System.debug method. Instead of using `Date.valueOf(...)`, consider `(''+ngaysinhTu).split(' ')[0]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I fix it just like you said by using ```String.valueOf(ngaysinhTu).removeEnd(' 00:00:00');``` I am just wondering, why does it have time in it. I thought that ```Date``` was for date only, it only has time when you use ```Datetime```.  But again, thank you for your help, kind sir.

Comment: @HungDoan Date and DateTime are interchangeable. This feature allows us to write queries such as `CreatedDate < :Date.today().addDays(-5)` for example. Without this time component, we would be forced to manually convert Date to DateTime values every time we wanted to query against a DateTime field. I was rather surprised when I found this myself, but it's just a quirk of Apex you'll have to come to accept.

Comment: thank you for your answer. That helped me a lot.